# How can my recorded data usage be 5x higher than what's shown in the apps list below it?

Tags: mobile-data

On the data usage screen, it says 1 GB used at the top, but if I add up the data from the list of apps below, it only adds up to about 180 MB. What are the possible causes?

I'm talking about this screen: https://cdn.guidingtech.com/media/assets/WordPress-Import/2015/09/ImageJoiner-2015-09-21-at-7.07.57-pm_result.png (not my actual screen, just an example)

And -- there's only 3 apps that really used any data (hotspot, maps and chrome) because the rest (about 10 others) only used less than 1MB and so it's really easy to see and I'm not miscounting.

I have an S7 Active running 7.0.

Comment: I have understood your question, but haven't quite understood those screenshots. In the screenshot everything looks fine. You gave an _example_ screenshot, but it is not sufficient, you need to give your device's actual screenshot so that we can understand the problem clearly.

Comment: No, I don't need to include a screenshot of my device. The screenshot wasn't even necessary -- I just wanted to be extra clear the screen I was referring to. All you need to know is the data usage summary at the top far exceeded the list of apps below. It is the default android data usage screen in the settings.

Comment: How often do you disconnect mobile data or are there frequent coverage holes on your daily way? How large is the data packet size your MNO uses for calculating the data usage (10KB, 100KB or larger)? Smaller data connections are rounded up to that value. In case of frequent disconnections this may end up in a lot of data usage by rounding up.

Comment: I solved this. It was due to having the wrong APN settings, which like Robert said, probably caused a lot of issues even though I was in an area of good coverage. It was an unlocked phone.